# Can Direct3D11 use volume tiled textures?

Tags: nvidia, direct3d

I would like to use volume tiled texture, but avoid use D3D12 in favor of D3D11. Is that possible?

[Volume Tiled Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/volume-tiled-resources) are defined in Direct3D12.

But [D3D11_TILED_RESOURCES_TIER_3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ne-d3d11-d3d11_tiled_resources_tier) exists already in Direct3D11 to indicate "support of Texture3D for Tiled Resources".

[NVIDIA "Sparse fluid" Slide 19](https://docplayer.net/20844046-Sparse-fluid-simulation-in-directx-alex-dunn-dev-tech-nvidia-adunn-nvidia-com.html) also hints at a "Feature Level 11.3" that is required for Volume Tiled Resources.

But [there is not such feature level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-downlevel-intro)?

Testing on a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 reports:

- `D3D11_TILED_RESOURCES_TIER_1` using a D3D11 FL11_0 device
- `D3D11_TILED_RESOURCES_TIER_2` using a D3D11 FL12_1 device
- [D3D12_TILED_RESOURCES_TIER_3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/ne-d3d12-d3d12_tiled_resources_tier) using a DX12 device

Similar on Intel HD Graphics 530:

- Tier 2 on DX11 device
- Tier 3 on DX12 device

Am I missing something?

Comment: I had believed that you need to call ID3D11Device::CheckFeatureSupport which then gives you a D3D11_FEATURE_DATA_D3D11_OPTIONS1 which contains the tiled tier support level.   Does your driver support 11.2 +?  Can you confirm the driver supports that DX11.  It may not.

Comment: Yes, I used ID3D11Device::CheckFeatureSupport / D3D11_FEATURE_DATA_D3D11_OPTIONS1 to get the tier values mentioned in the question.
What exactly do you mean by driver support 11.2+? How do I check it?
I use a ID3D11Device2. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: I believe you can derive (ID3D11Device3) and (ID3D11Device4) from queryinterface.  3 and 4 I can't remember, but they maybe limited to win 8 and 10.  Just strange that its not able to obtain obtain D3D11_TILED_RESOURCES_TIER_3 as this is a superset of D3D11_TILED_RESOURCES_TIER_2